# Ludwig van Beethoven "complete" 722 works in Chronological Order

Tags: classical-music, beethoven, romantic-period, classical-period

It is known that ["The compositions of Ludwig van Beethoven consist of 722 works"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven).

However,

- only about 138 of these works have Op opus numbers.
- about 228 (till WoO 228b) have WoO numbers. (WoO: "Werke ohne Opuszahl", German for "Works without Opus number")

Where can we find a list of 722 works listed in the chronological orders? And, do we have access to many of less-known work performances online (e.g., some Youtube channel, etc.)

Comment: This looks pretty good: http://www.lvbeethoven.co.uk/page27.html  I haven't added them all up to see if it's got 722 though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the Biamonti Catalogue. An online version with MIDI versions of some works is available [here](http://www.lvbeethoven.com/Oeuvres/ListBiamonti01.html).

Comment: +1 thank you this is what I wanted! very appreciated -- if there is a recording link to Youtube or some online mp3 sources to listen - it will be perfect!

Comment: Keep in mind that no catalog is going to be 100% accurate in terms of chronological order, as they include many unpublished works whose date of composition can only be guessed.  There is some debate over the exact dates on many of the more obscure pieces.  There are even a number of pieces in the WoO listings and even one Opus number (64) that are considered to not actually be Beethoven's but falsely attributed to him after the fact.

Comment: There were also some pieces excluded from the WoO listings as spurious that were later determined to be actual Beethoven compositions. I'm glad it's not my job to figure this stuff out.

Comment: @wonderich It’s Beethoven so most (all?) of it will have been recorded. If you have the Op or WoO number and the title it should be easy to find on e.g. YouTube or a streaming platform of your choice.